# Rendering list of items (images) and put in html panels (use javascript etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following structure in a web page:

```
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Suggestions</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h3><span class="label label-default">Provide Suggestions for users</span></h3>
                Need to put information
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap thanks to some information that I gathered from stackoverflow. From back-end I will be sending list of images and inside above "panel_body" I want to render the images and display it as shown in below wire frame.

[image]

What is the best way to accomplish this? I don't know javascript but if someone can point towards to similar example I could figure out. I have a feeling javascript can accomplish this but not really sure what I should look up for.

Comment: have you looked at the extensive list of templates that come with bootstrap docs? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your data being returned? Is it a JSON object or an array? That would be useful before submitting any solutions.

You can easily create multiple rows within the panel_body using a for loop accompanied by a create row function.

```
var createRow = function(i) {
    //create panelCol
    var panelCol = document.createElement("div");
    panelCol.className = 'col-md-' + i ;
    panelCol.innerHTML = '<h3><span class="label label-default">Provide Suggestions for users</span></h3>Need to put information';

    //apend to panelBody
    var panelBody = document.querySelector('.panel-body');
    panelBody.innerHTML += panelCol.outerHTML;
}
```

Here is an example I made up: http://jsfiddle.net/3rqC7/5/

Comment: This is fantastic, at the moment I am not really sure how the data will be return I am hoping to generate json. Two small things if you can add, is it possible to give a gray color to alternate elements? and how can I add a scroll bar?

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle, it now allows for overflow scrolling and applies a different CSS styling to alternating rows. http://jsfiddle.net/3rqC7/5/

Answer (score 1):

I am using open-source, free version Kendo UI [ListView control](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index), and defining the rows and columns within my Kendo ListView template.  It can bind to a JS array or JSON, and even handle communicating with the server remotely.  It worked well for me; it bridged the client-side gap while keeping with the bootstrap setup.

You can check out this [blog post](http://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/kendo-ui-lists-and-twitter-bootstrap-simplified/) for details.  It's pretty simple.

Comment: Working on a blog post to that effect; I will post it at some point in the near future.

Comment: oops its not free :( have to pass on that

Comment: No it is free, Kendo UI open source is free, ListView is included.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you there as far as layout is concerned. If the images you wish to display aren't dynamic, you can use simple img tags and supply the path to your image on the server as appropriate.

```
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Suggestions</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <h3><span class="label label-default">Provide Suggestions for users</span></h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="someImage.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details »</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If they're dynamic, then you'll need to know Javascript, I'm afraid.